# sum total from spans jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a jQuery function to calculate the total number from the span

```
var sumnormaltotal = 0;
$('span[id^="normaloffertotalspan"]').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    sumnormaltotal += parseInt(text, 10);
});
```

The function is working perfectly but I have some products where the price is starting with a pound sign like £1.50, but my result back will be 1, not 1.50 so for example if I choose the amount 2 for the specific product with that price the result back will be 2 instead of 3 can you help me with some ideas please.

Comment: use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: `parseInt` returns an integer.  1.5 is not an integer, it's a float

Comment: Hi guys i do apologise i change in the wrong place parseInt i change it in the right place now with parseFloat() and is working properly thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.normaloffertotalspan').each(function() {
  sum += +$(this).text()||0;
});
$("#subtotal").text(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >

 <span class="normaloffertotalspan" id="option-1">11.11</span><br>
 <span class="normaloffertotalspan" id="option-2">22.5</span><br>
 <span class="normaloffertotalspan" id="option-3">33.33</span>

</div>

<h3>Subtotal = <span id="subtotal">0.00</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use parseFloat() instead of parseInt() to achive