# how to do sum of two content html into jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two content which are :

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >Prime</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="Prime_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >Benif</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="benif_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >total</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="total_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every content have this example of value :

```
<script>
  console.log($("#benif_id").html()); //11.578.351 $
  console.log($("#Prime_id").html()); //5.877.210 $
</script>
```

I want to do `$("#Total_id") = $("#benif_id") + $("#Prime_id")` but it's not work.

I was doing like this :

```
<script>
  $("#total_id").text(parseFloat($("#benif_id").html()) + parseFloat($("#Prime_id").html()) + '$');
</script>
```

instead of

```
$("#total_id") = 17,455,561 $
```

Comment: i think that i need to delete $ character first after delete all separators to int value after i do the sum but i don't know how

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954687/6251232

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.text()` to get and set the value from/to the respective elements. You also have to convert the values to `Number()` before adding them. You also have to `replace()` the `$` with empty string so that it no longer remains in the text.

```
var benif = $("#benif_id").text().replace('$', '');
var prime = $("#Prime_id").text().replace('$', '');
$("#Total_id").text(Number(benif)  + Number(prime) + ' $');
```

Comment: i test your answer so i have NaN value to total_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#total_id").text((
parseFloat($("#benif_id").html().split('.').join("")) + 
parseFloat($("#Prime_id").html().split('.').join(""))) + '$')
```

removing the dots when parsing the number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for:

```
var benif = $("#benif_id").text().replace(/[.\s$]/g, '');
var prime = $("#Prime_id").text().replace(/[.\s$]/g, '');

$("#Total_id").text((+benif + +prime) + ' $');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$("#benif_id").html('11.578.351 $'); //11.578.351 $
 $("#Prime_id").html('5.877.210 $'); //5.877.210 $
  var Benif=$("#benif_id").html().replace(/\./g,'').replace('$','');
  var Prime=$("#Prime_id").html().replace(/\./g,'').replace('$','');
  var total=+Benif + + Prime;
 //alert(total.toLocaleString())
  $("#total_id").text(total.toLocaleString() + ' $');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >Prime</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="Prime_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >Benif</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="benif_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 >total</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 id="total_id" class="card-title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```